# Import local JavaScript Files into Single JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a wordpress site that loads a single `app.js` file filled with jQuery that handles functionality for the entire site. It is incredibly long and difficult to navigate. I would like to switch over to something like a SCSS partials approach, where I can create separate files for reusable code or single pages, and then load those files into one single `app.js` file.

I know that jQuery has a `$.getScript()` function, but my understanding is that I cannot use this while developing on my localhost, and that trying to load files stored locally will not work because of the nature of the `$.getScript()` AJAX request.

Are there other options that would allow me to create smaller snippets of js, and then import them into a single parent file? I would prefer not to load 25 separate scripts in my `<head>` for each reusable bit of js I write.

```
|--js
|  |-- app.js
|  |-- partials
|  |  |-- partialOne.js
|  |  |-- partialTwo.js
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Modules in the Browser (without WebPack)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492736/using-modules-in-the-browser-without-webpack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to export data from your "partial" .js files into modules and import into the app.js.

as a simple example, suppose your partialOne.js has functions to sum and multiple values:

```
let sum = (a,b) => {
    return a+b;
}

let multiply = (a,b) => {
    return a*b;
}

export {sum, multiply};
```

Here I'm using functions, but you can export anything, from arrays, objects, variables, etc. Now, in your app.js, you must import them:

```
import {sum, multiply} from "./file_path/partialOne.js"

console.log(sum(2,3));
console.log(multiply(5,5));
```

For more info on using modules, check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export